# PHP Replace values in an array into an HTML string

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

Sounds simple enough, but I'm feeling quite stupid today.

If I have an array like this:

```
$defined_vars = array(
    '{POST_TITLE}' => $item['post']['name'], 
    '{POST_LINK}' => $item['post']['link'], 
    '{TOPIC_TITLE}' => $item['topic']['name'], 
    '{TOPIC_LINK}' => $item['topic']['link'], 
    '{MEMBERNAME}' => $txt['by'] . ' <strong>' . $item['membername'] . '</strong>', 
    '{POST_TIME}' => $item['time'], 
    '{VIEWS}' => $txt['attach_viewed'] . ' ' . $item['file']['downloads'] . ' ' . $txt['attach_times'],
    '{FILENAME}' => $item['file']['name'],
    '{FILENAME_LINK}' => '<a href="' . $item['file']['href'] . '">' . $item['file']['name'] . '</a>',
    '{FILESIZE}' => $item['file']['size'],
    '{DIMENSIONS}' => $item['file']['image']['width'] 'x' $item['file']['image']['height'],
);
```

And a String like this:

```
$string = '<div class="largetext centertext">{POST_LINK}</div><div class="smalltext centertext">{MEMBERNAME}</div><div class="floatright smalltext dp_paddingright">{POST_TIME}</div><div class="dp_paddingleft smalltext">{VIEWS}</div>';
```

I need it to be replaced with the values of those keys.  Is that possible to do?  Perhaps using `str_replace()` somehow?  Are array keys allowed to have curly brackets within them?  Would that cause any problems?  Also, I need this to replace the $string value for ALL times these are found, cause it is possible to have the same output desired more than 1 time.  For example, if `{POST_TITLE}` is defined twice it should output the value twice exactly where they have used it at within the string.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($defined_vars as $key=>$value) {
  $string = str_replace($key,$value,$string);
}
```

this is using str_replace like you asked and it is easy to see what is happening.  Php also has the [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) or string translate function to do pretty much just this so you could also use

```
$string = strtr($string,$defined_vars);
```

but would have to remember what that function does.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is the simplest way to do it that will work

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for `strtr` function.  Didn't know that this was possible.  Marked this as my answer because strtr is faster, so it seems, than using `str_replace` with `array_keys` and `array_values`!  Thanks so much for this! :)

Answer (score 4):

[str_replace](http://bd.php.net/str_replace) supports array. The following syntax will do it.

```
$string=str_replace(array_keys($defined_vars), array_values($defined_vars), $string);
```

curly braces are supported in array keys because it's in string and strings are supported as array yes.

Comment: +1 I always forget about using array_keys/array_values this way

Comment: @Scuzzy happens to me too :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="largetext centertext">
  <a href="<?=$item['post']['link']?>"><?=$item['post']['title']?></a>
</div>
<div class="smalltext centertext">
  <?=$txt['by']?><strong><?$item['membername']?></strong>
</div>
<div class="floatright smalltext dp_paddingright"><?$item['time']?></div>
<div class="dp_paddingleft smalltext">
  <?=$txt['attach_viewed']?>
  <?=$item['file']['downloads']?>
  <?=$txt['attach_times']?>
</div>
```

well, if it's a user-defined string, you have to replace

```
$string = strtr($string,$defined_vars);
```

Also I hope you **filter out** user-edited HTML, to prevent them from stealing your cookies and login as admin or any other user.

Comment: Huh?  I need to replace `{POST_TIME}` within a string with the value of `$defined_vars['{POST_TIME}'];` and so on, for any other ones that are within the string.  This is a user-defined string, so it can hold any of the `$defined_vars` keys. The HTML, the user can change at any time via a textbox...

Comment: No need to bark. Polite explanation would be enough. for such a limited case here is another solution

Answer (score 0):

Yep, your str_replace is suitable, just foreach() loop your array

```
if(isset($defined_vars) and is_array($defined_vars))
{
  foreach($defined_vars as $token => $replacement)
  {
    $string = str_replace($token,$replacement,$string);
  }
}
```

you may want to apply some filters to your variables to ensure you don't have your HTML wrecked.

Comment: What do you mean by filters to the variables to ensure that the HTML is not wrecked??  And thanks btw :)

Comment: Why are you downvoting all the answers?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST eg if you need to escape any html to ensure clean output, or have you done that ahead of time?